# Django: URLs in django and adding it into templates

Tags: python, django, url

How to write URL in the template to take the request to this kind of URL - 
`path('category/<str:cat>/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='category')`

I am working on Django 2.1 and my urls.py contains multiple **str** path resolver.

```
path('<str:cat>/', SomeView1.as_view(), name='view1'),
path('<str:tags>/', SomeView2.as_view(), name='view2'),
```

But for these urls every request containing str only is captured by view1. To remove ambiguity I tried these URL patterns-

```
path('category/<str:cat>/', SomeView1.as_view(), name='view1'),
path('tag/<str:tags>/', SomeView2.as_view(), name='view2'),
```

Actually I added hard coded string like **category** and **tag**. But now I don't know how to write url in my template so that request can be made to these urls through HTML page.

normal

```
{% url 'view2' tag.name%}
```

is not working.

Please suggest how to add these links to my template or is there any alternate way to solve this issue.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You reference these two URLs just like any others.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have edited the question and tried to explain it in a better way. Please try to solve this issue.

Comment: Why is it "not working"? What happens? What error do you get? And do you have something called `tag` at that point in the template?

Answer (score 0):

In template use it like this {% url 'view1' cat='sam' %} {% url 'view2' tags='tag1' %}